# Access static cell when pressing button

Tags: swift, uitableview

My issue is pretty simple but I can't figure out how to do it. I have a static cell and a button inside it.

I have an `IBAction` hooked to the button.

**How do I access the cell inside the `IBAction`?**

I tried:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 1) as myStaticCell
    cell.height = 200
```

But for an unknown reason to me, it takes both lines as a single expression.

Comment: You probably need to use the `as!` operator.  What is the actual error you're seeing?

Comment: Expected ',' separator. `as!` didn't fix it.

Comment: The better way is to implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and an appropriate flag in the model. Then set the flag and reload the index path. In `heightForRowAtIndexPath` return the height for the index path depending on the flag.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I eventually did and it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the method call.  Add a second `)` before your `as` keyword.  You will also need to use `as!`.

You need to change:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 1) as myStaticCell
```

To this:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 1)) as! myStaticCell
```